# import android.content.*

Tags: android

Quando adiciono a linha "import android.content.*", ela fica cinza. Sem ela eu não consigo abrir outra ativity.

Tentei criar um projeto novo, mas continua com o mesmo problema. Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Está utilizando o Android Studio? Se estiver, ele deixa a linha cinza porque você ainda não utilizou a classe `Intent` no seu código, deixe o `import` como está e tente escrever seu código normalmente. Se der algum erro volte a reportar ele aqui para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Estou usando Android Studio. Quando escrevo "intent" e passo o mouse em cima, aparece a seguinte mensagem "Cannot resolve simbol 'Intent'".

E a linha "import android.content.*" permanece cinza.

Comment: Tente o seguinte, clique em Build e depois em Rebuild Project.

Comment: Não funcionou. Porem, eu criei um projeto novo, realizei todos procedimentos citados acima e funcionou. Eu vou seguir com este novo. Agradeço muito pela ajuda. Ela veio muito rápida!